# KB4343887 Causing stability issues

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-update

After the august 2018 cumulative update (KB4343887) was installed on our test servers, several things have become unstable.

The issues I've dealt with in the aftermath:

- One of the virtual servers lost its network adapter.
- When I select a scheduled task folder on a remote system on our management server, mmc crashes
- Our WSUS host has become unresponsive two times, requiring a reboot.
- Another server was unresponsive and had to be reset.

Are anyone else experiencing issues after updating?

I've put a hold on the update, and approved it for removal on our WSUS server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The September 2018 cumulative update has not caused the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

> There is an issue with Windows and third-party software that is
>   related to a missing file (oem.inf). Because of this issue,
>   after you apply this update, the network interface controller will
>   stop working.

and

> Patch Lady Susan here with a late Tuesday evening update to this post:
>   Microsoft has updated the known issues section and removed the
>   sections about the .NET/COM errors that were listed in July.  In my
>   early testing I haven’t seen side effects but I will be doing more
>   testing/more watching.  So for now hang loose and test and wait. 
>   Clearly they messed up the documentation in this month’s release and
>   copied and pasted the text from July’s releases.   The only known
>   issues left are the ones with Exchange (make sure you install with
>   admin rights) and the missing OEM note in Windows 7 (shown below).  In
>   ALL of my Windows 7 testing I have had zero issues and my
>   understanding this network interface problem is limited to VMware
>   (virtual machine) installs.  Thus I don’t anticipate that we will see
>   this on normal machines.

This is the feedback from Susan Bradley, she challenge and test a lot each update

More info [there](https://www.askwoody.com/tag/kb-4343887/)

Comment: To be honest, I don't see how it is an answer. The link which you've referenced doesn't talk anywhere about the problem with this update; it's just that the page has been tagged with that kb-article. I suspect the actual problem to be related to something else, if any!

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful This break the oem file, thus cutting the network card, it got reproduced in lab with that KB. The OP state it lost network too, so how it's not revelant ?

Comment: As I said previously, the statement mentioned there is related to Win7 Monthly Rollup. Same thing is also mentioned on Microsoft's website for the said patch. On the other hand, OP is talking about Windows Server 2016 update causing problem! So, this answer is currently not a valid answer IMHO.

Comment: The oem.inf thing does seem quite relevant.
As an update, today, that server died completely and had to be restored from backup.
This was a few days after uninstalling the update.